# Magento Product Image New server

Tags: image, magento

When I post a product, it's image shown in product listing page.But image not found error in product view page. 
I tried the following:

1. Checked permission of media folder and its subdirectories(0777)
2. renamed htaccess file in the media folder
3. checked gd library installed or not(installed)
4. image, small_image & thumbnail attributes; changed all these attributes have scope = Global
5. Increased memory limit in htaccess file
6. cleared cache
7. reindexed
8. image shown in listing page but the image not found in product description page.

Comment: Give url of the site

Comment: @Amnash Are the images visible on category page?

Comment: Images are showing in category wise listing page.But not shown in product description page.There shown the error as image not found

Comment: please check in backend image selected as base image or not?

Comment: @PrashantValanda : it selected as base image

Comment: here is the site link http://yardsaleforthesoul.com/  check the browse yardsle menu and view the item named Carousel of Hope Gift Bag

Comment: please deleted htaccess file under the media folder.clear all cache and rebuilt all indexes.

Comment: I reformatted your question to be a list so it is easier to read.  It is still unclear to me what you are trying to do.  Please update this post and add a specific question of what you are trying to do and what your expect results are.

Comment: problem fixed it was due to user/group permissions in new server.Thanks all

Comment: @AmnashAv could you pls explain briefly?